# Calling a rails function from javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'd like to trigger an action from my rails controller when the user leaves a page.
I fell onto the window.beforeunload event, but I don't know how I can call the function from my controller from the view.
I have something like this:

```
  //function that checks if someone leaves the page
  //if so, send mail to admin with unconfirmed reservation
function goodbye(e) {
    //:action => do_something

}
window.onbeforeunload= goodbye;
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you need an AJAX request here. remote_function can be handy here. Something like:

```
function goodbye(e) {
    <%= remote_function :url => { :action => "do_something" } %>
}
```

Comment: That does the trick indeed.
But extra problem. When i go to another page, my method get's called, but i get an error because no according view exists.
But all I want is that it does the action and then goes to the action which was clicked.
Any solution to this?